# Functional PCA for stationary signal

Tags: self-study, pca, fourier-transform, functional-data-analysis

I just came across this technique:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_principal_component_analysis

As far as I understand, if projects a signal onto a functional subspace that describe the "modes" with largest variation. These modes $f(t)$ are eigenfunctions of the correlation $G(s,t)=E[X(s)X(t)]$. I was just wondering if for stationary signals, where $G(s,t)$ depends only on $s-t$, this framework is equivalent to a Fourier decomposition on some discrete selected frequencies $\omega_k$.

My conjecture comes from the fact that in reciprocal space the operator $G(s,t)$, depending
only on time differencies, should be multipicative, even if than I am a bit confused on how to find the frequencies, if this is the case.. Maybe in such a case we have an infinite number of eigenvectors ($e^{i\omega t}$), each one with a different eigenvalue ( equal to $\tilde G(\omega)$ ) ? But than how can such a PCA version be useful ?

If the statement, or one variation of it, is true, is there some Python/R framework implementing this ?

Comment: As the eigenfunctions are derived from the data themselves they are non-parametric while Fourier polynomials would be purely parametric. I would think that we can accept wavelets as a middle ground (and there are quite a few publications on that, e.g. [Morris & Carroll (2006)](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9868.2006.00539.x), [Pigoli & Sangalli (2012)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167947311004518), etc.), if you want to explore a basis that explores localisation both in time and frequency.